# ColdFusion 10 - ORM Child Object Search & Calculations

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

have a pretty simple relationship already ORM defined in CF10. We have temperature sensors that have a many-to-one relationship defined in the tempSensor object to Buildings.

### tempSensors ORM persistent component

id_tempSensor - PK
currentReading - Integer value
id_Space - many-to-one relationship to below PK

### spaces ORM persistent component

id_space - PK
name - string
description - string

I want to do two things with this relationship:

1. Write a function in the 'spaces' component that returns an array of all the tempSensors objects that are mapped to to it. Ordering/sorting of results is not critical; we can re-order if necessary using standard CF array functions.
2. Write a function in the 'spaces' component that calculates the average temperature reading amongst all the tempSensors mapped to that space. So if there are five temp sensors mapped to that space, add up all the current temp readings, divide by five and return out the result.

I have looked all over for an easy solution to #1, maybe HQL to define a simple query?

I am thinking HQL might be the fastest and most efficient for #2, as we are going directly to the persistence layer, rather than return results in CF, instantiate objects and run arithmetic against the CF objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you define the one-to-many relationship on your Space for property `sensors` of type array, then the function you're looking for is just getTempSensors() that returns the array of sensors.
2. once you got #1 working, just loop through the array and calculate your avg temp.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WS5FFD2854-7F18-43ea-B383-161E007CE0D1.html#WSDDE3349B-ECE1-450d-B5B1-0BCACDCC6736

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking the same thing, doing a one-to-many on the Space object, but was wondering if 'crossing the streams' and mapping two relationships for the two objects was the right fundamental architectural decision.

Comment: @user3033620 bi-directional mapping is actually the preferred way of setting up these ORM relationships.  However, make sure your code maintains the truth, e.g. when you add a new Sensor in Space's collection, make sure the Sensor sets the Space as well.  The generated accessors do not do it for you automatically.